# How to take screen shot of MDI form while clicking on any Toolstrip menu item

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, screenshot

The below mentioned C# code that i had tried but at the time of taking the snapshot, the picture also contain the part of opened file menu. I need some help to capture the screen after the click event and before the save button is clicked but it should not contain the part of opened file menu

```
private void saveImageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    String filename = "";           
    Bitmap screen = new Bitmap(network_drawing_panel.Width, network_drawing_panel.Height - 50);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(screen))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(0, 80, 0, 0, screen.Size);
    }



    //   SaveFileDialog
    SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
    dlg.InitialDirectory = @"C:\\images";
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".jpg";
    dlg.Filter = "JPEG Images (.jpg)|*.jpg|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    dlg.Title = "Save an Image file";

    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        filename = dlg.FileName;          


        try
        {
            screen.Save(filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
        catch (Exception c)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());
        }


    }

}
```

this is the snap shot i got.

Comment: *"I need some help to capture the screen after the click event and before the save button is clicked"*. This just isn't going to happen. The `Click` event occurs when the save button is clicked. There's no interval in between for you to take photographs.

Comment: I dont't know but isn't there something like PreviewMouseDown in WinForms, too?

Comment: @Tokk: I don't know what `PreviewMouseDown` is. I suppose that's a WPF thing, but I don't use WPF. That event doesn't make a lot of sense to me. How do we know *before* the mouse button gets clicked that it's about to get clicked? Time travel hasn't been invented yet. And that still won't help you in this case—the menu will still be visible on the screen, so it'll still get included in your screenshot.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Yes it is WPF stuff, but because of this I wrote "something like [...] in WinForms". There is no need for TimeTravel _(btw. if you've got a flux-compensator it is no problem)_ because Framwork fires this before the normal Event is fired, so it is **before** MouseDown is fired. But I see, that it wouldn't solve the problem. But what about closing the menue programaticaly before taking the shoot?

Comment: @tokk: i tried to programmaticaly close this menu but i wasnt able to do that...can u suggest me any way or paste some code regarding it. I tried fileMenu.PerformClick(); but it wasnt working.

Answer (score 0):

The native way to do this is to use PostMessage. This allows the current dispatch to fully complete before performing the operation.

For WinForms the PostMessage equivalent is [Control.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) (a Form is a Control). WinForms actually uses PostMessage to execute delegates from BeginInvoke.

Comment: @ tergiver: can u please expand what u are trying to say

Comment: @aman: Refactor your code into a method and call `this.BeginInvoke(new Action(MyScreenShotMethod))`.